What need to be changed to fix nullabilty warning CS8765 in an overriden property?
I’ve created a working component based on WinForms’ UserControl. I’ve overridden a couple of existing properties that generate warning CS8765.
CS8765: Nullability of type of parameter 'value' doesn't match overridden member (possibly because of nullability attributes).

This code places the warning on “set” .
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the font of the text
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true)]
    public override Font Font
    {
        get => base.Font;
        set
        {
            base.Font = value;
            AdjustSize();
        }
    }

If I change the property's type from “Font” to “Font?” the warning for “set” goes away, but I get a different warning on “get”.
CS8764: Nullability of return type doesn't match overridden member (possibly because of nullability attributes).

This makes sense to me because the original declaration that I’m overriding uses the non-nullable version of Font.
Without ignoring it, how do I fix my original warning?

Font apparently has the AllowNull attribute, allowing you to call its setter with null. See the source here.
Effectively, the setter's parameter becomes nullable, but the getter returns a non-null value. That's why neither Font and Font? match the nullability. You need to add the [AllowNull] attribute to your override too.
[AllowNull]
public override Font Font
{
    get => base.Font;
    set
    {
        base.Font = value;
        AdjustSize();
    }
}


Many thanks! Was going in circles, trying to fix this.
